# calculating values based on the form input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to calculate the values in the form . output should be in same form and same line.

```
 echo '<td id="textone_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['fee']. '</td>'; 
                echo '<td id="texttwo_'.$row['id'].'" align="center"> 
        <input type="number" min="0" max="999" 
             name="cnt"     value="0"   
              onkeyup="sum('.$row['id'].');"></td>';
                 echo '<td> <input type="text" 
           name="result_'.$row['id'].'" id="result"></td>';

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

          <script>
          function sum(rowid) {
             var txtFirstNumberValue =  
           document.getElementById('textone_'+rowid).innerHTML;
           var txtSecondNumberValue = 
            document.getElementById('texttwo_'+rowid).value;
                 var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + 
                parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
                    if (!isNaN(result)) {
                    document.getElementById('result_'+rowid).value = result;
                  }
                  }
                 </script>
```

I try with this but no reply in my form . what mistake i did

Comment: Check your browser console for errors. What do you see?

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.min.js:13)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Please update your code to show us what you're actually have. Currently, it looks like you're trying to use HTML and JS inside a PHP-block (which I don't think you actually are since that would throw a parse error)

Comment: @kvr That's probably an unrelated error. Try typing a value into your input field and look at the error messages that show up then.

Comment: `textone` refers to a table cell `td` which does not have a value - it has innerText / innerHTML -so the same for `texttwo`

Comment: If the html / php code snippet above is from a database lookup and there are multiple rows ( as suggested by the `"output should be in same form and same line"` ) then the above code would fail regardless of  the misuse of the `.value` attribute because it would seem there would be multiple duplicate ID attributes which would render the HTML invalid and cause the javascript function to operate with the same selection each time regardless of which input element is changed

Comment: you cannot use document.getElementById('textone').value; on <td> element as <td> don't have 'value' attribute

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the first line of the js `function sum()`

```
var txtFirstNumberValue =  document.getElementById('textone').innerHTML;
```

You should use innerHTML instead of value if you are accessing value from non input field

If you have multiple row then you have to do something like this

HTML/PHP

```
echo '<td id="textone_'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['fee'].  
  '</td>'; 
 echo '<td id="texttwo_'.$row['id'].'" align="center"> 
  <input type="number" min="0" max="999" 
  name="cnt"     value="0"   
  onkeyup="sum('.$row['id'].');"></td>';
  echo '<td> <input type="text" 
   name="result_'.$row['id'].'" id="result"></td>';
```

$row['id'] can be replaced with the primary key or unique field of the table

JS

```
<script>
 function sum(rowid) {
        var txtFirstNumberValue =  document.getElementById('textone_'+rowid).innerHTML;
       var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('texttwo_'+rowid).value;
       var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('result_'+rowid).value = result;
       }
   }
  </script>
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I try . no changes in my form

Comment: echo '<td id="textone">'.$row['fee'].  '</td>'; 
                    echo '<td id="texttwo" align="center"><input type="number" min="0" max="999" name="cnt" value="0"   onkeyup="sum();"  ></td>';
                    echo '<td> <input type="text" name="result" id="result"></td>'; 

                     echo '<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" value="' . $row['certificate_id'] . '" name="certid[]" class="chb"></td>';

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 function sum() {
        var txtFirstNumberValue = 
 document.getElementById('textone').innerHTML;
       var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('texttwo').innerHTML;
       var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
           document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
       }
   }
  </script>

Comment: @kvr do you have multiple td with id ='textone' means are you printing the <tr><td>  in loop??

Comment: try debuging by placing alert() after each statment

var txtFirstNumberValue =  document.getElementById('textone').innerHTML;
alert(txtFirstNumberValue );
var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('texttwo').value;
alert(txtSecondNumberValue );
 var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
alert(result);
       if (!isNaN(result)) {
alert(result+' i am in if');
           document.getElementById('result').value = result;
alert('done');

       }else{
alert('Result is NaN');}

Comment: yes . it has 7 rows returned from db. each row has different fees.

Comment: thts tha issue js cant handel multiple element with same id

Comment: please check my updated answer, but still not working. should i add any js file

Comment: did you tried debugging as i said    by puting alert after each statement and checking console log

Comment: it returns :The specified value "texttwo_1" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: txtSecondNumberValue is error returned.when i use firstnumber in the console it return values. only error in second variable

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at sum (register_check:179)
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (register_check:117)